# How is Hölder's inequality and Parseval's identity applied here?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, semigroup-of-operators

I am reading this lemma from Pazy's semigroup of linear operators

[image]

I am having a hard time understanding

1- Why does the highlighted part hold?

2- How is the  Hölder's inequality applied and how the coefficient $q = 2p/(2+p)$ is chosen? The way I see it is that we want  $1 \leq r,t \leq \infty$ such that

$$ \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \left|( 1+ |\xi|^2)^{-p} ( 1+ |\xi|^2)^{q} |u(\xi)|^q\right| d \xi \right)^{1/q} \leq \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} ( \left|1+ |\xi|^2)^{-p}\right|
 d \xi \right)^{1/r} \cdot \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \left| 1+ |\xi|^2)^{q} |u(\xi)|^q\right|^t d \xi \right)^{1/t} $$

but I don't know where to go from here.

3- How is the last inequality deduced? Assuming we apply Parseval's identity $ \int |f(x)|^2 dx = \int |\widehat{f}(\xi)|^2 d \xi$ for $f \in L^2$, the second to last line reads

$$ \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} ( 1+ |\xi|^2)^{-p} d \xi \right)^{1/p} \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} ( 1+ |\xi|^2)^{2}) |u(x)|^2 d x\right)^{1/2} $$

but I still don't see how the last inequality holds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Question 1: Depending on what definition you use, this is precisely the definition of $H^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$. See this question for more details: [Sobolev spaces fourier norm equivalence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232942/sobolev-spaces-fourier-norm-equivalence)

Question 2: Matching Hölder exponents is something you get a feeling for and need to try out for yourself, there is no highroad to just guessing the exponents. In this case, you want to find a $q$ such that
$$
\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{q}
$$
and rearranging for $q$ yiels $q=\frac{2p}{p+2}$. The rest is simplifying exponents after applying the following version of Hölders inequality
$$
||fg||_q \leq ||f||_p ||g||_2
$$
for $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{q}$.

Question $3$:
$$
\bigg( \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}(1+|\xi|^2)^{-p}d\xi \bigg)^{\frac{1}{p}}
$$
is just a constant, independent of $u$. Then, like in the first part, we have
$$
||u||_{H^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}^2=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}(1+|\xi|^2)^2|\hat{u}(\xi)|^2 d\xi.
$$
But now you have
$$
||u||_{H^2(\mathbb{R}^n)} \leq C(||u||_2+||\Delta u||_2)
$$
for some $C$ independent of $u$ by the other definition of Sobolev spaces involving weak derivatives. You have to use the (infamous) lemma
$$
||D^2u||_2=||\Delta u||_2 
$$
here. However, I don't really see how you would apply Parsevals here directly, however, it is implicitly used in part 1 again.

Comment: The variants are the ones that are killing me in analysis.

Comment: With time, you will get an intuition of "what should be true" and then you just have to do a bitch of searching :-)